# Ocelot Consul - Error Leasing load balancer

Tags: c#, consul

I'm using version 11.0.2 of Ocelot and Ocelot.Provider.Consul.  Below is my ocelot.json file.

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/v1/vaults",

      "ServiceName": "testservice",  
      //"LoadBalancer": "LeastConnection",
      //"LoadBalancerOptions": {
      //  "Type": "LeastConnection"
      //},
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/values",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey":  "OcelotRequestId", 
    "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 8500,
      "Type": "Consul"
    }
  }
}
```

When I submit the request, I get the following log information.

```
requestId: 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Unable to use service Address: http://localhost and Port: 56736 as it is invalid. Address must contain host only e.g. localhost and port must be greater than 0
dbug: Ocelot.LoadBalancer.Middleware.LoadBalancingMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: there was an error leasing the loadbalancer, setting pipeline error
warndbug: Ocelot.LoadBalancer.Middleware.LoadBalancingMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: There were no services in NoLoadBalancer
warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: ServicesAreEmptyError Message: There were no services in NoLoadBalancer errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/api/values, request method: GET
dbugdbug: Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline finished
```

Do I have soemthing misconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

I had my service registered with Consul using http://localhost in the Consul address field.  I removed the uri.Scheme and added DownstreamScheme to my ocelot configuration file and everything works.

Thanks to @TomPallister for the help in the github respository for [Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot).

Comment: Thank you for response, I got the same issue, After your answer, I solved it.